# Nginx: Rewriting directory path to file

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm a little new to Nginx here so bear with me -

I want to rewrite a url like `foo.bar.com/newfoo?limit=30` to `foo.bar.com/newfoo.php?limit=30`.

Seems pretty simple to do it something like this `rewrite  ^([a-z]+)(.*)$  $1.php$2 last;`

The part that I am confused about is where to put it - I've tried my hand at a some location directives but I'm doing it wrong.

Here's my existing virtual host config, where should I implement my rewrite?

```
server {
listen   80;
listen   [::]:80;

server_name foo.bar.com;
root /home/foo;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /index.html;
```

Comment: Ohhh I get it, cool. Totally approached that wrong I guess. Cheers.

Comment: Just a note, I got this to work by putting it at the top of the .php file location directive, and renaming that directive to `location / {}`. Thanks again